# Concepts and resources for a simple 2D fluid simulation with collision

Tags: 2d, simulation, fluid, particles

I decided it would be fun to program a basic 2D fluid/liquid simulation with collision. There are tons of approaches and I am not sure where to get started. I'd like to only cover 2D, however I would like to have gravity and collision, in a way, that other objects would interact with the fluid.

Something like this comes to mind:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kbladin/Fluid_Simulation/master/images/big.gif

What algorithms are typically used for such a scenario?
Are there any good papers that explain this in a not to complicated manner?
Where do I get started?

If possible I would like to avoid any frameworks/libraries that ship all the required functions as I would like to write them myself to get a better understanding on the subject.

I am considering using C# and visualizing this by drawing dots on a canvas. I assume the forces of each particles can be  represented in a multi dimensional array of some sort, however I still don't know where to get started. Any recommendations?

Comment: Very cool animation.  I am not aware of any open source libraries that can do this out of the box.  I develop physics based simulations for just this type of phenomenon and "not complicated" is a matter of opinion.  Are you trying to model the behavior of the fluid using a particle simulation?  Or are the dots in the animation simply pixelation of the continuum?

Comment: I'd like to do it for a fixed amount of particles. I am not sure about the gif, its just a random example I found to emphasize what I was referring to.

Comment: So, you don't want a continuum equation, like fluid dynamics.  You seem to want a particle simulation that generates the macro properties of a fluid.  You would then need to model the "stickiness" of the particles.

Comment: @ggcg I see. Are there any papers that explain this in a not to complex fashion? What can get me started with this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not too complex.  You could try a text on Mechanics of fluids.

Comment: @ggcg Can you link me any papers/tutorials/guides ..? I am not sure where to start.